# WooCommerce does not send Order Confirmation email to customer anymore

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am facing a really strange issue in my WooCommerce shop. For a couple of days the "customer_processing_order" email is not sent to the customer anymore. Even when I trigger manually sending this email inside the order details, nothing happens.

In general email, sending works with SMTP data. When I set the status to "Completed" the email is sent. It is only the order confirmation which is not working.

The email is activated and I also checked error logs. I also installed the Preview Plugin for order emails. When I want to generate the preview, I am getting an error:

> CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_billing_first_name() on null in /usr/www/users/diabroq/diabrothers/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/woocommerce/emails/customer-completed-order.php:28

I don't know if this is related ... normally it was working.

I also installed WP Email Logs Plugin. No emails are generated, so it is not an email delivery issue. The emails that are working have a successful log entry.

I hope somebody can help me ...

Comment: You have an error in your theme on the line referenced. It's critical according to what your post says. Post your code from that...

Comment: I have the same theme for another shop ... i compared the files ... and they are identical. So i dont think it is related to the Theme. And this error only happens for the email preview plugin. even for the "completed" email, it is not working there.

Comment: Please post the code from the file.

Comment: Here is the code: https://nopaste.xyz/?e8cdcb69144e2a88#mvwOJdRhSlUmoudbxPOgJRbH2xFHbgIno+WBDcy9tNo=

Comment: The error also happens when i am using the default woocommerce template:

> 2020-02-19T10:58:15+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_billing_first_name() on null in /usr/www/users/diabroq/diabrothers/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/customer-on-hold-order.php:26

Comment: Is this for a real order with billing info?

Comment: yes, its a normal order

Comment: The order object is no being found. There is something very wrong.

Comment: We have 2 issues here ... one is the broken Preview Plugin and one is the fact, that no order confirmation email is sent to the customer even if it is activated.

The second issue is most critical. How can i debug this ...

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue. It was related to this plugin: "Email Text Customizer for WooCommerce"
After deactivating it was working again ... oh man!